# Firestore rules allowing to read even when not allowed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, react-admin

I want to create Firebase Firestore rules so that only verified users can read and write into the members collection. But I seem to be unable to write such firesore rules.

I wrote those Firestore rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }       
  
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /members/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.verified == true;
    }
  }
}
```

But they don't seem to be working. Even if I try this, which is the most alarming part:

```
    match /members/{document=**} {
      allow read: if false;
    }
```

I can still read the data in my application. I can even update the documents in the Firebase web UI and they will also update in my React-admin app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `match /{document=**}` match statement overlaps your `match /members/{document=**}` statement.

And with

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
}
```

any authenticated user can read and write to your entire Firestore DB.

See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#overlapping_match_statements) for more details on Overlapping match statements:

> It's possible for a document to match more than one match statement.
> In the case where multiple allow expressions match a request, the
> access is allowed if **any** of the conditions is true.

---

Generally speaking it is not recommended to keep a default `match /{document=**}` statement. You should write a dedicated set or rule for each collection/subcollection and remove the `match /{document=**}` statement and rules.